# Error while using Python to connect to Amazon RDS Postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to Amazon RDS Postgresql database with this python code

```
import psycopg2
engine = psycopg2.connect(
    database="vietop2database",
    user="postgres",
    password="07041999",
    host="vietop2.cf4afg8yq42c.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    port='5433'
)
cursor = engine.cursor()
print('opened database successfully')
```

I encountered an error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "vietop2.cf4afg8yq42c.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.161.159.194) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

I consulted this [trouble shooting on amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html) and I already make sure the DB instance's public accessibility is set to Yes to allow external connections. I also changed port to 5433 and set VPC security to default. Yet, I fail to connect to the database. What might be the reasons? Please help me. Thank you very much

Below are the database connectivity and configuration information

[image]

[image]

Comment: you probably don't want to share db access information to a publicly accessible database on the internet...

Comment: @monkut thank you for reminding me, but don't worry because this is just my personal database created for my own practices.

Comment: If it's timing out and you cannot connect, it's probably a security group issue.  Check that your security group ingress is open to connections for that port.

Comment: @monkut Does that mean I need to specify the VPS rule to allow access? P/s I am using the Datacamp workspace to code. https://www.datacamp.com/workspace

Answer (score 2):

It is a Security group related issue, try to specify the inbound settings for your database.

And avoid to make it open for any connection.

Comment: I had the same issue and I edited my inbound settings, and allowed all traffic from ipv4 and ipv6. It worked for me, but what should be my actual inbound rules.